# How to rename GCS files in Spark running on Dataproc Serverless?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

After writing a spark dataframe to a file, I am attempting to rename the file using code like below:

```scala
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(path + "/part*"))(0).getPath().getName()
fs.rename(new Path(path + "/" + file), new Path(path + "/" + fileName))
```

This works great running Spark locally... However when I run my jar on Dataproc, I get an error like below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong bucket: prj-***, in path: gs://prj-*****/part*, expected bucket: dataproc-temp-***
```

It seems files may not be saved to target buckets until the end of the job, and therefore struggling to rename them. I have tried using the `.option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")` as I read something about this that looked promising.

Update:
Still no luck. It seems that `spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration` expects the base bucket to be a `dataproc-temp-*` bucket. Full stack trace below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong bucket: prj-**, in path: gs://p**, expected bucket: dataproc-temp-u***
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.checkPath(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.makeQualified(FileSystem.java:667)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.makeQualified(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:394)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.getGcsPath(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:149)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.globStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1085)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.globStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1059)
```

Answer (score 2):

HCFS instance returned by `FileSystem.get(...)` call is tied to the specific FS (in this case GCS bucket). By default Dataproc Serverless Spark configured to use `gs://daptaproc-temp-*/` bucket as a default HCFS via `spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS` Spark property.

To solve this issue you need to create HCFS instance using [`FileSystem#get(URI uri, Configuration conf)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#get-java.net.URI-org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration-) call:

```scala
val fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri, spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
```